# RxJava: how to sample but repeat when unchanged

Tags: rx-java

I want to construct an Observable which always emits the most recent and possibly repeated(!) value of an Observable `x` every time another Observable `t` ticks. I cannot use `x.sample(t)` because that will not emit repeated values of `x` if there is no change between subsequent ticks of `t`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.

```
  public <T, F> Observable<T> answer(Observable<T> values, Observable<F> trigger) {
    return Observable.combineLatest(values, trigger, Pair::of)
        .distinctUntilChanged(p -> p.getRight())
        .map(Pair::getLeft);
  }
```

Where `Pair` is a simple java bean with `left` and `right` value.